# Adding value to cells in Google Sheets from a button displayed in the sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am creating a form using Google Sheets where I would like the list of options in the sidebar, where you can click on the option in the sidebar, and the value will be added to the spreadsheet. How do I get the button in the sidebar, when clicked, to run a function that will perform the task of adding the necessary rows and data to the spreadsheet?

I have found many ways to get the data from the spreadsheet to show up in the sidebar. What I need is for the data to go from the sidebar to the spreadsheet. I have the code to manipulate the spreadsheet as I need, see Snippet1, I just can't figure out how to connect that code to the button.

Snippet1:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var saas = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

function addLine() {
  var lastRow = lastRowValue('b');
  var nextRow = lastRow + 1;
  var dataColA = ['=MAX(A4:A'+ lastRow + ') + 1'];
  var dataColB = ['New Line'];
  saas.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
  ss.getRange('A' + nextRow).setValue(dataColA);
  ss.getRange('B' + nextRow).setValue(dataColB);
}
```

Snippet2:

```
<input type='button' value='Click to Add' onClick='<?!= addLine() ?>'/>
```

I have tried to use directly in my HTML form the code:

(See code Snippet2)

But that runs the code on load and not when I click the button.

Comment: [Read](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I used the following, `<input type='button' value='Click to Add' onClick='google.script.run.addLine()' />`. That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
`<input type='button' value='Click to Add' onClick='addLine()'/>`.

When I press the button, it runs the code that you put above.

Comment: I've tried that way as well. Unless I am missing something in the code, that doesn't do anything for me either. Am I supposed to put code in the ".gs" file so that they connect?

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I used the following, `<input type='button' value='Click to Add' onClick='google.script.run.addLine()' />`. That worked.